# atributes in web.xml are not working eclipse kepler

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring, maven

I am using Spring 3, Apache-maven-3.2.2, Apache-tomcat-7.0.54.

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
```

It is giving compile time error

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'web-app'.
    - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd', because 1) 
     could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

Answer (score 1):

The very first line in web.xml should be:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`

Also you can use the following tag:
`<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">` instead of the one that you are trying if possible. Here version used is 3.0 instead of 2.5 that you are trying.

Please note that version 3.0 should be used if you are using Java EE 6 compliant servers.

Comment: You shouldn't just change version like this. Version 3.0 should only be used for Java EE 6 compliant application servers.

Comment: Yes that's why I said if possible :)

Comment: I think you should have explained the difference between the two.

Comment: But you did. I appreciate.